# Buildr doesn't find JAVA_HOME from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, buildr, java-home

I have Buildr installed on Ubuntu and it works fine running from command line. I've also installed the Buildr plugin for Intellij IDEA. But I can't run commands such as `compile` from the IDE. It gives the following message:

```
/usr/local/bin/buildr compile
(in /path/to/project, development)
Compiling scala-spike
Compiling scala-spike into /path/to/project/target/classes
Buildr aborted!
RuntimeError : Are we forgetting something? JAVA_HOME not set.
```

But `JAVA_HOME` *is* set. The command `echo $JAVA_HOME` prints the correct path where Java is installed.

Comment: Where is your JAVA_HOME set exactly? You must ensure your JAVA_HOME is when IDEA is launched, e.g., check in `$IDEA/bin/idea.sh`

Comment: Sorry, the answer solved the problem, but I forgot to accept it. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are passing `JAVA_HOME` while starting idea.sh.
Try starting IDEA with `sh -c "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java && $IDEA/bin/idea.sh"`